# VPN client creation on Ubuntu with strongswan fails

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, strongswan, l2tp, vpn-client, xl2tpd

I've set up a L2TP VPN server on my home router and the connection between Windows 10 clients works properly. Now I want to set up a VPN client on a Ubuntu 18.04 machine. I've used this configuration (x.x.x.x is the static IP of my home router and y.y.y.y is the private IP of my ubuntu machine):

**/etc/ipsec.conf**

```
config setup
     virtual_private=%v4:10.0.0.0/8,%v4:192.168.0.0/16,%v4:172.16.0.0/12
     nat_traversal=yes
     protostack=netkey            
     plutoopts="--interface=eth0" 

conn L2TP-PSK
     authby=secret
     pfs=no
     auto=add
     keyingtries=3
     dpddelay=30
     dpdtimeout=120
     dpdaction=clear
     rekey=yes
     ikelifetime=8h
     keylife=1h
     type=transport
     left=y.y.y.y
     leftprotoport=17/1701
     right=x.x.x.x
     rightprotoport=17/1701
```

**/etc/ipsec.secrets**

```
y.y.y.y x.x.x.x : PSK "pre_shared_key"
```

**/etc/xl2tpd/xl2tpd.conf**

```
[lac vpn-connection]
lns = x.x.x.x
ppp debug = yes
pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/options.l2tpd.client
length bit = yes
```

**/etc/ppp/options.l2tpd.client**

```
ipcp-accept-local
ipcp-accept-remote
refuse-eap
require-mschap-v2
noccp
noauth
idle 1800
mtu 1410
mru 1410
defaultroute
usepeerdns
debug
connect-delay 5000
name vpn_username
password password
```

Unfortunately I'm getting the below error:

```
$ sudo ipsec up L2TP-PSK
initiating IKE_SA L2TP-PSK[5] to x.x.x.x
generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ]
sending packet: from y.y.y.y[500] to x.x.x.x[500] (1302 bytes)
received packet: from x.x.x.x[500] to y.y.y.y[500] (36 bytes)
parsed IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
received NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN notify error
establishing connection 'L2TP-PSK' failed
```

Unfortunately I can't find any other logs :(

Thanks a lot!
Luca

Comment: A possible issue could be that the router might only support the _modp1024_ DH group, none of the stronger ones strongSwan proposes. So try configuring e.g. `ike=aes128-sha1-modp1024` (you could maybe also check the router config to see what algorithms it actually expects/supports).

Comment: Hi, unfortunately nothing changed. I'm getting the same error. ANd I can't find any clues of which algorithm my router supports :(

Comment: The router might not support IKEv2, so try setting `keyexchange=ikev1`.